# How to make React ignore one route?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, routes, react-router

I'm working on a project that, for reasons too long to get into, at one point needs to redirect the user to the API. The problem is that the API and the React front end are on the same domain. So when the browser requests `mydomain.com/api/blahblahblah`, it gets picked up by React Router and never reaches the API.

I need React to ignore requests to that one particular route and to let the API handle it.

The app is hosted on Heroku so there's a chance this is a Heroku issue, not a React issue.

Comment: Yes this is a Heroku problem since it routes to the React Router first than your API.

Comment: Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply use the good old anchor tag (a tag) you should get the desired effect.

Also, you can trigger a redirect using JS:

```
<MyComponent onClick={ () => window.location.href = 'this/awesome/url/' } />
```